# RestClientException Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type

Tags: java, json, jackson, lombok

I have following PoJo:

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class KostenpflichtigeBuchung {
    private String buchungZahlungsId;

    private String warenkorbId;

    private String pseudocardpan;

    private Zahlungsmittel zahlungsmittel;

    private String landKreditkartenInhaber;

    private String nameKreditkartenInhaber;

    private String touchpointId;

    private String vertriebspartnerId;

    private Kundendaten kundendaten;

    private Fulfillmentart fulfillmentart;

    private final List<Reisender> reisenderList = new ArrayList<>();

    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> payload;

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getPayload() {
        return payload;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setPayload(String name, Object value) {

        if (payload == null) {
            payload = new HashMap<>();
        }
        payload.put(name, value);
    }
}
```

When I execute a cucumber Test on it, I get the following Exception:

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class de.db.vendo.bue.buchung.model.KostenpflichtigeBuchung] and content type [application/json;charset=utf-8]

    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:917)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:655)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:613)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:531)
```

I have some other test and other POJO with the same annotation which are working without any problems. I have really not a single idea what is going wrong.

Thank for any suggestion!

Comment: Have you checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32616943/no-suitable-httpmessageconverter-found-for-response-type-custom-resttemplate) already?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably issue between **lombok** constructor annotations and related generated constructors, often when I face this error, I just revert response class to @NoArgConstructor only and try again.

If you really need all these constructors and builders, try to code them manually and go with @JsonCreator like describe in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39123030/jackson-json-deserialization-with-multiple-parameters-constructor).